# Retrofit + Rx java Observable issue

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

Getting some issue using RXjava + Retrofit, Plz Help

Json like :

https://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json

Error screensort below :

[image]

Code Below:

```
CallInterface movieApiInterface;
Call call;
public final static String BASEURL="https://api.androidhive.info/json/";

private OAuthManager(){}

public static OAuthManager getInstance(){
    if(instance==null){
        instance=new OAuthManager();
        instance.getClient();
    }
    return instance;
}

private void getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASEURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        movieApiInterface = retrofit.create(CallInterface.class);
    }
}
public interface CallInterface {
    @GET("movies.json")
    Observable<List<Movies>> getMoviesList();

}

public Observable<List<Movies>> getMovieApiData(){
    return movieApiInterface.getMoviesList();
}
```

It working fine with simple Retrofit Call but facing this issue on Observable.

Comment: which proguard rules did you use?

Comment: this just test demo, I am not using any proguard rules , using default android studio proguard file

Comment: The `com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0` you are using is depreciated. Try [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2).

Answer (score 1):

From the code I see there is no issue, why not trying using any RxJava2CallAdapterFactory of rxjava2? I'm thinking when it got the value of json and trying to store the value, it's got stuck in .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()) that's why it's return error

I can give some example of my implementation using Retrofit so u can use it as reference

in my gradle:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.12'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1"
implementation "com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-extensions:0.18.9"

implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0"
implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1"
```

and this is my ApiClient:

```
public class ApiClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient;


public static Retrofit getClient() {

    if (okHttpClient == null)
        initOkHttp();

    if (retrofit == null) {

        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(
                        Travel.class,
                        new JsonTravelSerializer())
                .create();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

private static void initOkHttp() {
    int REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 60;
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);

    httpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {
        Request original = chain.request();
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Request-Type", "Android")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    });

    okHttpClient = httpClient.build();
}}
```

in the class you need to call

```
apiservice = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
.....
disposable.add(apiService
            .getJson()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JsonObject jsonObject) {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String jsonOutput = jsonObject.get("data").toString();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<TravelData>>() {
                    }.getType();
                    List<TravelData> travelData = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
                    travelList.clear();
                    travelList.addAll(travelData);

                    adapter = new MainViewAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                    adapter.addAll(travelList);
                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }
            })
    );
```

Comment: I'm using implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0"

Comment: yes, problem was RxJavaCallAdapterFactory,  I was using 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0, now it's working

Answer (score 1):

Depends on version of Retrofit that has imported is `2.4.0` in your project, you added a deprecated version of [Retrofit2RxJava2Adapter](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter):

```
implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0"
```

> Retrofit 2.2 and newer have a first-party call adapter for RxJava 2:
>   https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2

You just replace this and use like:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.5.0'
```

and

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
       .baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL)
       .client(okHttpClient)
       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
       .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()) // replace this line
       .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you change your endpoint as below and try again pls.

```
public interface CallInterface {
    @GET("movies.json")
    Observable<Movies> getMoviesList();
}

public Observable<Movies> getMovieApiData(){
    return movieApiInterface.getMoviesList();
}
```

Please let me know about result.